# parse xml whose attribute include double quote with lxml

Tags: python-3.x, lxml

I can't get an xpath research on the attribute "Frais de Services" with lxml:
I have an xml file whose content is the folowing:

> ```
>   <column caption='Choix Découpage'   name='[Aujourd&apos;Hui Parameter (copy 2)]'>
>             <alias key='&quot;Frais de Services&quot;' value='Offline Fees' />
>   </column>
> ```

```
from lxml import etree
import sys
tree = etree.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
print([node.attrib['key'] for node in root.xpath("//alias")]) # we get ['"Billetterie Ferroviaire"']
```

I tried many hack, none works (i can't understand why lxml change internally the original "Predefined entities"):

```
root.xpath('//alias[@key="\"Frais de Services\""]')
root.xpath('//alias[@key="&quot;Frais de Services&quot;"]')
```

Comment: Try `root.xpath("//alias[@key='\"Frais de Services\"']")`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i already tried but get an empty list :(

Comment: are you sure? the output that i get is ```['"Frais de Services"']```

Comment: Oh yes you are right! Sorry and thanks a lot. PS: now my problem is that i can't write dynamically "//alias[@key='\"Frais de Services\"']" since python string are always simple quote ... Have you an idea ? Or should i ask an other question in another post ?

Comment: @DanielHaley's suggestion (and deleted answer by @ExplodingGayFish) does work.